# Laravel relationship with multiple fields using OR clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to build a simple chat app and I have these models
User
Contact
Message

the user model has this relation:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
}
```

The Contact Model has this relation:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany(Message::class, 'sender_id', 'user_id')
        ->orWhere('receiver_id', '=', $this->user_id); //this is the mistake
}
```

This is what I am trying to execute

```
User::with(['contacts' => fn($q) => $q->with('messages')])->get()
```

The message has sender and receiver columns which I want to load the message on these conditions using "Where or Where"

but I couldn't do that.

I found awobaz/compoships package which seems like a solution for multiple conditions but it uses "Where and Where" which is not my case. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

The messages are related directly to the user with the attribute `sender_id`.

User model

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'sender_id');
}
```

The messages have a relation with contact (i'm guessing `receiver_id`)

Message model

```
public function receiver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class, 'receiver_id');
}
```

You can get all messages with the contact related to them

```
$user = User::with('messages.receiver');
```

If you need the messages for only one contact

```
$contactId = 5;
$messages = $user->messages()->whereHas('receiver', function($receiverQB) use ($contactId) {
    $receiverQB->where('id',$contactId);
})->get();
```

Comment: The same thing if I called the relation directly from the User, The senario is when the User open the list of chats, he should see the contacts "first relation", and then messages from contact which maybe "He sent or He received", so it cant be a direct relation, I need a "Where sender_id = user_id or receiver_id = user_Id"
I hope u got the idea..

Comment: @MahmoudBenJabir add these important details to your question.